# How to add values to the Room database

Tags: android, android-room

I have 2 string Values in "DetailActivity" which have to be added to Room database based on "Favourites" objects.How do i do that?

DetailActivity:

```
 String img= detailItems.get(position).getImage().toString();
 String title = detailItems.get(position).getTitle().toString();
```

Favourites class:

```
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "fav_table")
public class Favourites {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private String title;
    private String image;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }



    public Favourites(String title, String image ) {
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;

    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

DetailActivity contains list of image and titles and on clicking certain images in generates the img url and title and stored in a variable as shown above. those variables have to added to the "Favourites" database.
I have setup the Room database which is working fine. I just want to know how to add data to the database from " DetailActivity"

thanks in advance for assistance

Answer (score 0):

With a the following in a interface or abstract class that has been annotated with @Dao then you would have :-

```
@Insert
long insert(Favourites favourites);
```

Then ensuring the you could use (assuming that `dao` has been appropriately  instantiated)

```
dao.insert(new Favourites(title,img));
```

or

```
dao.insert(new Favourites(detailItems.get(position).getTitle().toString(),detailItems.get(position).getTitle().toString()))
```